# Can I left join twice to do multiple calculations?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I am trying to calculate if a member shops in January, what proportion shop again in February and what proportion shop again within 3 months. Ultimately to create a table similar to the image attached.

I have tried the below code. The first left join works, but when I add the second one to calculate within_3months the error: "FROM keyword not found where expected" is shown (for the separate line). Can I left join twice or must I do separate scripts for columns?

```
,  count(distinct B.members)/count(distinct A.members) *100 as 1month_retention_rate
```

```
select 
      year_month_january21
,   count(distinct A.members) as  num_of_mems_shopped_january21 
,   count(distinct B.members)as  retained_february21
,  count(distinct B.members)/count(distinct A.members) *100 as 1month_retention_rate
,  count(distinct C.members)/count(distinct A.members) *100 as within_3months
from 
    (select 
        members
    ,   year_month as   year_month_january21 
    from table.members t
    join table.date tm on t.dt_key = tm.date_key
    and year_month = 202101
    group by
        members
    ,   year_month) A
left join 
    (select 
        members
    ,   year_month as year_month_february21 
    from table.members t
    join table.date tm on t.dt_key = tm.date_key
    and year_month = 202102
    group by
        members
    ,   year_month) B on A.members = B.members
left join 
    (select 
        members
    ,   year_month as year_month_3months
    from table.members t
    join table.date tm on t.dt_key = tm.date_key
    and year_month between 202102 and 202104
    group by
        members
    ,   year_month) C on A.members = C.members
group by 
      year_month_january21;
```

I have tried left creating a separate time table and joining to this. It does not work. Doing calculations separately works but I must do this for multiple time frames so will take a long time.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Why do you GROUP BY in the subqueries?

Comment: Do your subqueries work when executed independently?

Comment: As the error implies this is Oracle not MySQL, this isn't from the left join, it's from `as 1month_retention_rate`, because it's an illegal name - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6aG7Y4dz).

Comment: This is using Oracle SQL Developer and the subqueries work independently.

Comment: SQL Developer is a client. Presumably you're connecting to an Oracle database, and the error you got was preceded with the code ORA-00923, which it would have been helpful to include. But why have you tagged the question with MySQL as well as Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

The error isn't coming from the added left join, it's from the `as 1month_retention_rate` part, because it's an illegal name.

You can see that more simply with:

```
select dummy as 1month_retention_rate
from dual;
```

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

You could change the column alias so it follows the naming rules (specifically here, does not start with a digit), or if that specific name is actually required then you could make it a quoted identifier - generally not a good option, but sometimes OK in the final output of a query.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6aG7Y4dz)

So in your code you would just change your new line

```
,  count(distinct B.members)/count(distinct A.members) *100 as 1month_retention_rate
```

to something like

```
,  count(distinct B.members)/count(distinct A.members) *100 as one_month_retention_rate
```

or with a [quoted identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA)

```
,  count(distinct B.members)/count(distinct A.members) *100 as "1month_retention_rate"
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Kq6nNcC) - which still errors but now with ORA-00942 as I don't have your tables, and that is after changing your obfuscated schema/table names to something legal too.

There may be more efficient ways to perform the calculation, but that's a separate issue...

Comment: Or alternatively, the OP needs to use a quoted identifier for this alias.

Comment: Sure, no problem; I see what you mean so I've added it as an example too. Even though I don't like to encourage their use *8-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multiple joins, count the shops per member per month and then use conditional aggregation.

In Oracle, that would be:

```sql
SELECT 202101 AS year_month,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt_202101 > 0 THEN 1 END)
         AS members_shopped_202101,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt_202101 > 0 AND cnt_202102 > 0 THEN 1 END)
         AS members_retained_202102,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt_202101 > 0 AND cnt_202102 > 0 THEN 1 END)
       / COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt_202101 > 0 THEN 1 END) * 100
         AS one_month_retention_rate,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt_202101 > 0 AND (cnt_202102 > 0 OR cnt_202103 > 0 OR cnt_202104 > 0) THEN 1 END)
       / COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt_202101 > 0 THEN 1 END) * 100
         AS within_3months
FROM   (
  SELECT members,
         year_month
  FROM   members m
         INNER JOIN date d
         ON m.dt_key = d.date_key
)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR year_month IN (
    202101 AS cnt_202101,
    202102 AS cnt_202102,
    202103 AS cnt_202103,
    202104 AS cnt_202104
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could understand that you want to get :

- count of all members who visited in Jan.
- count of all members who visited in Jan and visited again in Feb.
- count of all members who visited in Jan and visited again in Feb, Mars and April.

If my understanding is true then you could simplify your inner query using IF instead of LEFT JOIN .
Take a look on the following query. Assuming that table members have an ID field :

```
SELECT
  mem_jan AS num_of_mems_shopped_january21,
  mem_feb AS retained_february21,
  mem_feb / mem_jan * 100 as 1month_retention_rate
  mem_3m / mem_jan * 100 as within_3months
FROM(
    SELECT
      SUM(IF(mm_jan>0,1,0) AS mem_jan,
      SUM(IF(mm_jan>0 AND mm_feb>0,1,0) AS mem_feb,
      SUM(IF(mm_jan>0 AND mm_count_3m>0,1,0) AS mem_3m
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
          t.Id,
          SUM(IF(year_month = 202101, 1,0)) AS mm_jan, /*visit for a member in Jan*/
          SUM(IF(year_month = 202102, 1,0)) AS mm_feb, /*visit for a member in Feb*/
          SUM(IF(year_month between 202102 and 202104,1,0)) AS mem_3m/*visit for a member in 3 months*/
        FROM 
          table.members t
          join table.date tm on t.dt_key = tm.date_key
        WHERE
          year_month between 202101 and 202104
        GROUP BY
          t.Id
    ) AS t1
) AS t2
```

This is not a final running query but it can explain my idea. According to your engine you may use `CASE` or `IF THEN ELSE`